# Problem in installing GCC (G++) 5 in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, c, g++, compiler

I needed gcc 5 on my ubuntu 22.04. I tried using "sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5" but this output is coming:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-0+fast-big5-hanzi-encode-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs+less-slow-big5-hanzi-encode-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libonig5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libini-config5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libsuitesparseconfig5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libkf5plotting5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libqt5positioning5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librlog5v5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libkf5notifyconfig5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libapt-pkg5.0' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'qtpositioning5-examples' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-0.8+less-slow-big5-hanzi-encode-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'liboxygenstyleconfig5-5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-0.8.22+less-slow-big5-hanzi-encode-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-0.8.22+fast-big5-hanzi-encode-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libnanomsg5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'liballegro-dialog5.2' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libinotify-ocaml-dev-zqg59' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libkf5syntaxhighlighting5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'qtpositioning5-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'qtpositioning5-doc' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'qtsvg5-doc-html' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libqt5svg5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'qtsvg5-doc' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'qtpositioning5-doc-html' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libkf5akonadisearchdebug5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs+fast-big5-hanzi-encode-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'liballegro-dialog5-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libqt5svg5-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libroot-montecarlo-eg5.34' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libinotify-ocaml-zqg59' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librlog5' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libipmimonitoring5a' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libqt5positioning5-plugins' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-0.8+fast-big5-hanzi-encode-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'qtsvg5-examples' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-0+less-slow-big5-hanzi-encode-dev' for regex 'g++5'
Note, selecting 'libinotify-ocaml' instead of 'libinotify-ocaml-zqg59'
Note, selecting 'libinotify-ocaml-dev' instead of 'libinotify-ocaml-dev-zqg59'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-dev' instead of 'librust-encoding-rs+fast-big5-hanzi-encode-dev'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-dev' instead of 'librust-encoding-rs+less-slow-big5-hanzi-encode-dev'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-dev' instead of 'librust-encoding-rs-0+fast-big5-hanzi-encode-dev'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-dev' instead of 'librust-encoding-rs-0+less-slow-big5-hanzi-encode-dev'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-dev' instead of 'librust-encoding-rs-0.8+fast-big5-hanzi-encode-dev'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-dev' instead of 'librust-encoding-rs-0.8+less-slow-big5-hanzi-encode-dev'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-dev' instead of 'librust-encoding-rs-0.8.22+fast-big5-hanzi-encode-dev'
Note, selecting 'librust-encoding-rs-dev' instead of 'librust-encoding-rs-0.8.22+less-slow-big5-hanzi-encode-dev'


E: Unable to locate package gcc-5
```

Now what does last line indicate ...any solution. I have already added the repository using "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test" and have done sudo update.
It still is showing same result.

Comment: `gcc-5` is *deprecated* and was available for releases up to 18.04 (*bionic*) in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Thank you guiverc....should i install gcc 7 then?

Comment: What do you see as output from `$ gcc --version` ? - isn't that suitable? What kind of project would not work with it?  You might need `$ sudo apt install build-essential ` though.

Comment: Why not just install the default version; ie. `sudo apt install gcc` will install `gcc | 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1  | jammy           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` ( https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gcc ) ie. gcc 11

Comment: I need gcc5 and this will give gcc11.2.0.......guiverc

Comment: version 11.2 is not suitable....i need 5 version.....build essential is required in later stages.......Hannu

Comment: gcc-7 is likewise *deprecated*, but was last available on 20.04 (`gcc-7 | 7.5.0-6ubuntu2       | focal/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x`)   Use *focal* (20.04) on a VM for your compiles maybe...

Comment: Thank you guiverc

Comment: Hi friends this is what I found:                I tried a lot guys....gcc5 cannot be installed on ubuntu...but gcc7 .5 can be installed.                For gcc5 you have to install ubuntu 18 bionic